# Sort Bars in stacked bar charts Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am creating a bar chart on Apache Superset which shows count of something from across the world breakdown by platform. My chart looks like this
[image]

I want to change the order of appearance of breakdown values, WIN should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of your metrics  to match the order you want.